# How to get AWS API Gateway invoke URL in an AWS Lambda function?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, url, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm using the proxy integration with my Java lambda function. The input for the lambda handler is a JSON object that represents an incoming request. It has a body, headers, query params and so on. But it doesn't include the source URL that is parsed by the API Gateway for the body, query params and etc. Is there a way to get it?

The thing is API Gateway doesn't support arrays in query parameters. Example: `/endpoint?numbers=1&numbers=2`. Seems, the only way to pass an array is to pass it as a JSON array string `/endpoint?numbers=[1,2]` but it is not always suitable. So I want to parse the URL by myself.

Comment: Has this changed at all, or has anyone found a way to get the full URL since this was posted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, API Gateway doesn't provide you with the full URL for you to parse yourself.

If you have the option of using the `POST` method to `/endpoint`, you might consider sending a request body instead of query string parameters.

Comment: Has this changed at all, or has anyone found a way to get the full URL?

Answer (score 0):

The 'path' field inside the 'requestContext' field contains the path of API gateway resource. See [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda.html#api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda-test) for more details.

Comment: The "path" value does not include the query params portion of the request url.

Answer (score 0):

you can inject the UriInfo object. It holds all the information you need.

```
@Context
UriInfo uri;
```