# Accessing raw url using AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Is it possible to access the raw url using AWS API Gateway (and Lambda)?

Alternatively, is it possible to access the original, undecoded query string paramters?

We are integrating against a third party service, that calls our API and encodes the query string params from Windows-1252. (E.g. the finnish letter Ä is encoded as %C4 instead of %C3%84). API Gateway seems to automatically decode the query string parameters and assume UTF-8, which means, that Ä (and Ö and Å) result in \ufffd.

For reference: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: I think not. ApiGateway by default decode all query parameters. But you can alway encode them back if you like

Comment: The problem is, I can not encode them back, because all non-ascii characters result in \ufffd (replacement character used when the decoding fails.)

Comment: Did you try adjusting your template mapping like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/33143297/383839

Comment: Is there something special about that approach? I did try creating the mapping myself, but when iterating `$input.params().querystring` the values are already decoded.

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49372722/how-to-get-aws-api-gateway-invoke-url-in-an-aws-lambda-function

Answer (score 6):

Damn, it really doesn't look possible...

I started off writing how you can use [Lambda Proxy Integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda.html) with `event.queryStringParameters`, but that parses the data into a key-value object.

Then I went down the road of [Mapping Templates](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html) in API Gateway, but again there doesn't seem to be any property that shows the whole querystring.

As much as I didn't want it to be true, I can only conclude that it is not possible...

I think your best option is to encode the parameter as base64 on the client, then decode in the Lambda function using `Object.keys(event.queryStringParameters)[0]`.

Comment: Thanks for trying to investigate this, even though it wasn't the answer I was hoping for. I really don't understand, why don't they pass on the raw url to be processed as you please...